# why is the product of gain and bandwidth constant for an amplifier?

Tags: amplifier

why is the product of gain and bandwidth constant for an amplifier? IS this statement always valid or holds true under certain conditions only?

Answer (score 5):

It only holds true for amplifiers whose bandwidth is limited by a 1st order capacitance such as Miller Capacitance on an BJT or the internal C compensation  for an Op Amp.  But for many types of Video and RF amps these configurations are not applied and hence are the same rules do not apply.

If a 1st low pass filter reduces -6dB per octave as found in the Miller intrinsic capacitance or the internal compensation of an OP Amp , we know -6dB means 1/2 Voltage and octave means x2 frequency so 1/2V x 2f = 1 for a normalized constant gain bandwidth.

Substitute the baseline gain and break point frequency or take the GBW product in order to determine 1 variable by choosing the other.

Comment: Can you also please answer the first part of the questions?

Comment: The math gives the answer. Do you have the math>

Comment: It doesn't even hold true under all conditions for an op-amp (as BW->0 for example) but I don't think we should be doing his hw for him.

Comment: Typical Op Amp has a breakpoint of 10 Hz and gain of 1e6 for a 10MHz GBW, so >0 never applies.  Its more like > 10Hz for open loop gain slope. with a wide range of alternatives.  But they never explained this at Uni in my day, so I thought it was worth the effort. if they do now the "quick fox runs around the lazy student".